# WSPBuilder questions for first-time webpart

Tags: sharepoint, wspbuilder, sharepoint-2007

I have made my first webpart using WSPBuilder. When I try to deploy it using STSADM, I get an error stating access is denied. I am an admin on the machine (well it's a VM).

Also, with WSPBuilder, do I need to change the config files (I assume no as the point of the tool is to automate this)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could two reasons for your problem

1. Even though you are the admin of the system you may not have privilege in central Administration. So login in the system with the user name of sharepoint administrator and try to deploy it.
2. There may be a problem in the way you created the WSP. if you deploy webpart using WSP then there is no need to edit the config file manually. Recently I have created a blog which explain how to create simple webpart, creating WSP and deployment. If interested check it out http://www.allaboutmoss.com/index.php/2010/03/22/hello-world-sharepoint-webpart-for-beginners/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't have enough permissions to add the webpart. What OS are you on? If it's Windows Server 2008 R2 etc you will have to run the command prompt as an administrator or turn off UAC for administrators. As for the config WSP builder will create you a file called solution.txt which contains the Id for your solution. For more control over what it is doing you can add a WSP Builder config file to your project called "WSPBuilder.exe.config". An example one can be found in "C:\Program Files\WSPTools\WSPBuilderExtensions".

Answer (score 0):

Go to --> RUN--> SERVICES.MSC--> check the following service is started or not.
Windows SharePoint Services Administration, if not pls start this service. if the wsp is deployment done. go center admin--> Operations    -->Global Configuration -->Solution management . This page has a list of the Solutions in the farm. check ur wsp in this list.